# What is the algorithm to find the maximum sum of an array sub-sequence?

Tags: c, data-structures

There is an 1-D array with elements {5,30,99,60,5,10}.
From this array, 1 sub-sequence is 5, 99 and 10 which sums up to a value of 114. Other sub-sequences sum are lesser than 114.
Two elements should not be contiguous in the sub-sequence ie {5, 30 and 60} is not a valid sub-sequence (for this problem). It can be either {5, 99, 5} or {30, 60, 10} etc. The array doesn't contain negative numbers. 
What approach will be the right way to calculate this maximum sum? I am trying to implement it in C.

Comment: There is an algorithm for that but is difficult to explain. You can read it [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/maximum-subarray-sum-using-divide-and-conquer-algorithm/)

Comment: @babaliaris It looks like that algorithm doesn't meet the constraint that the sequence may not be made from adjacent list items.

Comment: @babaliaris that is for contiguous elements..

Comment: You can modify it to implement them. It might be a difficult task to do but optimization algorithms are hard by their nature. You will need to work that out a lot in order to be able to implement what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recursion is your friend here

Sum is the maximum of

`5 + maxSum of {99, 60, 5, 10}`

or discard 5 in favor of 30 and

`30 + maxSum of {60, 5, 10}`

Assuming you do not have any negative numbers, you should use either `5` or `30` and then the remaining sequence. Discarding both of them does not make sense.